# MySql query to get results based on timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, session, timestamp

Here, Im trying to get some details based on the difference between two timestamps i.e.,
there is a modified column which stores a timestamp, and there is created column from another table which also stores a timestamp.
what i need is timestamp(created) between timestamp(modified) and timestamp(current time).
Plzz help

Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'

select * from campaigns where created BETWEEN timestamp(Array) AND timestamp(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())

Filename: models/Notification_model.php

Line Number: 11

```
<?php
class Notification_model extends CI_Model 
{
    public function notifications()
    {
        $q1="select modified from influencer where influencerid=".$this->session->userdata('id')."";
        $query1 = $this->db->query($q1);
        $this->session->set_userdata('modified_time',$query1->result());

        $q="select * from campaigns where created BETWEEN timestamp(".$this->session->userdata('modified_time').") AND timestamp(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())";
        $query = $this->db->query($q);

        if($query->num_rows()>0){
          return $query->result();
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: How does your $q variable look, if you var_dump($q) it ?

Comment: I dont know about var_dump()

Comment: it prints the value of $q so you know if your query is right. Just put var_dump($q) in your code and look / post the output

Answer (score 0):

Your `$query1->result()` is returning an array, you should take the first row, and the first column (`updated`):

```php
$modified_time = $query1->result()[0][0];
```

Moreover, it's a very bad idea and a big security issue to do this:

```php
$q1="select modified from influencer where influencerid=".$this->session->userdata('id')."";
```

You can be hacked with SQL injection. For example, if I define the ID to:
`1; UPDATE users SET is_admin = 1`, the SQL request becomes:
`select modified from influencer where influencerid=1; UPDATE users SET is_admin = 1`, and I'm admin of your system.

You should prepare your statements to prevent this hack:

```php
$query = $this->db->prepare("select modified from influencer where influencerid = :id");
$query->bindParam(':id', $this->session->userdata('id'));
$query->execute();
```

More info here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php